# "Overflow" Error (6) when doing calculations on arrays

Tags: vba, excel

I am creating a macro in VBA which finds values in one sheet and uses them to populate array MyArr(11,4) and then does calculation. Find and populating part works great, problem is the latter part.

```
.Range("C2").Value = MyArr(11, 4) / MyArr(11, 1)
.Range("D2").Value = (MyArr(9, 4) + MyArr(10, 4) + MyArr(11, 4)) / (MyArr(9, 1) + MyArr(10, 1) + MyArr(11, 1))
.Range("E2").Value = (MyArr(0, 4) + MyArr(1, 4) + MyArr(2, 4) + MyArr(3, 4) + MyArr(4, 4) + MyArr(5, 4) + MyArr(6, 4) + MyArr(7, 4) + MyArr(8, 4) + MyArr(9, 4) + MyArr(10, 4) + MyArr(11, 4)) / (MyArr(0, 1) + MyArr(1, 1) + MyArr(2, 1) + MyArr(3, 1) + MyArr(4, 1) + MyArr(5, 1) + MyArr(6, 1) + MyArr(7, 1) + MyArr(8, 1) + MyArr(9, 1) + MyArr(10, 1) + MyArr(11, 1))
```

This is the fragment of code in question. It causes Overflow error (6). I know this error happens due to one of the values in array being empty. Is there an easy way to stop using empty values but still execute the code for the filled ones? So if for example MyArr(9,4) is empty it would still execute the 2nd line of code because there are values in (10, 4), (11, 4) with omitting (9,4).

If the rest of the code is needed please inform me.

Comment: Either look before you leap (test the denominator before division) or use error handling to respond to any errors that might pop up.

Comment: Be sure to **Dim MyArr as Double**

Comment: More code (but not necessarily the *rest* of the code) would help. In particular -- you are leaving out the declarations. Please give a [mcve].

Comment: We need to see how `MyArr` is declared. If everything is implicitly typed, Specifically which instruction is overflowing? The 2nd one? What does `TypeName(MyArr(9,4))` say, and what kind of values are involved? See [VBA data types](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=339929&seqNum=2) - like @JohnColeman said, we don't need *the rest of the code*, just *enough* to know what we're looking at.

Comment: Declaration is `Dim MyArr(11, 4)`. Declaring it as a double doesn't help because then we have division by 0 and the "Overflowing" error still occurs. The Overflowing instruction is the first line but I don't know whether an empty value in an array will affect also other lines of code (can you sum filled values and empty values?). Values that calculation are done on are numbers (including decimals) summing up to 10e15. Sorry for scarce information in my entry post.

Comment: I know I could just use On Error Resume Next but I'm not sure whether it won't affect all the calculations where empty array values are used (by skipping whole calculation and not only the empty value).

Comment: `On Error Resume Next` does not fix anything. It lets your code keep running *ignoring all errors*, i.e. you can't know what your code does anymore... which is usually a Bad Idea™. It doesn't *handle* errors - it downright *ignores* them!

Comment: Error handling is a natural approach for this sort of thing. `On Error Resume Next` *by itself* isn't adequate and is even harmful (as @Mat'sMug points out). The only disciplined way to use it is if you explicitly check `Err.Number` after statements that can cause errors and handle them as needed. A more reliable way is to use the construct `On Error GoTo err_handler` where `err_handler` is a label for a block of error handling code. See this: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ErrorHandling.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Jon mentioned, check for division by zero before doing the division:

```
If MyArr(11, 1) <> 0 Then 
  .Range("C2").Value = MyArr(11, 4) / MyArr(11, 1)
Else
  .Range("C2").Value = 0
End If

If (MyArr(9, 1) + MyArr(10, 1) + MyArr(11, 1)) <> 0 Then
  .Range("D2").Value = (MyArr(9, 4) + MyArr(10, 4) + MyArr(11, 4)) / (MyArr(9, 1) + MyArr(10, 1) + MyArr(11, 1))
Else
  .Range("D2").Value = 0
End If

If (MyArr(0, 1) + MyArr(1, 1) + MyArr(2, 1) + MyArr(3, 1) + MyArr(4, 1) + MyArr(5, 1) + MyArr(6, 1) + MyArr(7, 1) + MyArr(8, 1) + MyArr(9, 1) + MyArr(10, 1) + MyArr(11, 1)) <> 0 Then
  .Range("E2").Value = (MyArr(0, 4) + MyArr(1, 4) + MyArr(2, 4) + MyArr(3, 4) + MyArr(4, 4) + MyArr(5, 4) + MyArr(6, 4) + MyArr(7, 4) + MyArr(8, 4) + MyArr(9, 4) + MyArr(10, 4) + MyArr(11, 4)) / (MyArr(0, 1) + MyArr(1, 1) + MyArr(2, 1) + MyArr(3, 1) + MyArr(4, 1) + MyArr(5, 1) + MyArr(6, 1) + MyArr(7, 1) + MyArr(8, 1) + MyArr(9, 1) + MyArr(10, 1) + MyArr(11, 1))
Else
  .Range("E2").Value = 0
End If
```

Comment: Solution that you and @John proposed might be the easiest, when not sure if handling it by On Error Resume Next is proper. Thanks!

Comment: Never use `On Error Resume Next` - All it takes is one ignored error and the problems are bound to get worse as the code continues.

Comment: @braX never say never.  `On Error Resume Next` has its place, but it should be used rarely and always followed by `On Error Goto 0` directly after.